# How to configure a default node to execute rundeck commands against?

Tags: rundeck

I am looking for a solution to have a default, already selected, node to run commands against in rundeck.

I am relatively new to rundeck and I do want to be able to execute commands without having to always use the pick-node dropdown process.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this feature is missing so I added a new feature request at https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/1551

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, this would be done with:

1) making sure you select "target nodes are selected by default" within the job definition
2) add your node(s) to "matched nodes" via the "node filter"

Now when the job is executed, the node(s) will be automatically selected.

Comment: I know that this would work for **jobs** but if you want to use the execute tab, which is one per project, unrelated to a specific job, it seems that you are out of luck as I was not able to find any option to configure the default for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such settings for default node to execute adHoc commands.. you can set this for jobs but not for executing adhoc commands at the moment.. All you can do is. saving a specific "filter" from nodes tab.. so it would easy for you to select from drop down..

Another method of automating this is, using API.. You can execute adhoc commands using api where you can mention the node name with filter.

http://rundeck.org/docs/api/#running-adhoc-scripts

Hope this helps